# Unit Testing with Range Function

Tags: python, unit-testing, for-loop, range

I will try to be as clear as possible. I've been practicing unit testing for a while now, and I'm now trying to figure out how to test the below code.

```
def main():

    for i in range(100):
        print("Argh!")
```

So I'm just trying to test for the 100 iterations of "Argh!" to make sure that the stdout passes the test. I'm not even sure how to even start the unit test. on This one, although it looks very simple.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using python3, this becomes easy with a mock...

```
import unittest
import mock  # possibly "from unittest import mock" depending on version.
import main_module

class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main(self):
        with mock.patch.object(main_module, 'print') as mock_print:
            mock_module.main()
        expected_calls = [mock.call('Argh!') for _ in range(100)]
        mock_print.assert_has_calls(expected_calls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```